# How can i merge an array with variable values

Tags: php

I couldn't find it on Google, or used the wrong keyword. How can i merge a variable value "[contestant**variable_number**-fieldname]" to a multidimensial array?

Example of the array:

```
array (
  [contestant1-gender] => M
  [contestant1-first-name] => Wyatt
  [contestant1-last-name] => Heath
  [contestant1-occupation] => Ipsa architecto vol
  [contestant1-email] => dipuxo@mailinator.com
  [contestant1-phone] => +1 (992) 741-8123
  [contestant2-gender] => M
  [contestant2-first-name] => Leonard
  [contestant2-last-name] => Acosta
  [contestant2-occupation] => Aut sunt qui offici
  [contestant2-email] => sajomogylu@mailinator.com
  [contestant2-phone] => +1 (462) 687-8393
  [department] => In mollitia impedit
  [street] => Sed error magnam obc
  [number] => 41
  [bus] => In iste ut perspicia
  [postalcode] => Commodo impedit vol
  [city] => Ad iure veniam veli
  [country] => nl
)
```

To something like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => contestant (
     [0] => gender ( )
     [1] => first-name ()
   )
   [1] => contestant (
     [0] => gender ( )
     [1] => first-name ()
   )
   [2] => contestant (
     [0] => gender ( )
     [1] => first-name ()
   )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: you can use the function `array_merge_multidimesional` you just have to write it first :D

Comment: What are the `()` in the result supposed to be?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854400/flat-array-to-nested-by-keys and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573147/expand-dot-notation-keys-in-a-nested-array-to-child-arrays for methods to convert keys like `contestant-gender` to nested arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this at least approximates that for which you are looking:

```
$array = [
   'contestant-1-gender' => 'M',
   'contestant-1-first-name' => 'Wyatt',
   'contestant-1-last-name' => 'Heath',
   'contestant-1-occupation' => 'Bl;ah blah',
   'contestant-2-gender' => 'M',
   'contestant-2-first-name' => 'Leonard',
   'contestant-2-last-name' => 'Acosta',
   'contestant-2-occupation' => 'Foo',
   'department' => 'Who cares?'
];

$contestants = [];
array_walk($array, function($val, $key) use (&$contestants) {
   if (preg_match('/contestant\-(?P<id>[\d+])\-(?P<field>.*)/', $key, $matches))
   {
      $contestants[$matches['id']][$matches['field']] = $val;
   }
});

print_r($contestants);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [gender] => M
            [first-name] => Wyatt
            [last-name] => Heath
            [occupation] => Bl;ah blah
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gender] => M
            [first-name] => Leonard
            [last-name] => Acosta
            [occupation] => Foo
        )

)
```